# Нужно ли тире в предложении "Вижу сны, а в них (-) тебя"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в предложении "Вижу сны, а в них (-) тебя"?

Answer (score 1):

**Вижу сны, а в них ― тебя.** Тире поставлено на месте пропущенного сказуемое "вижу".

**Это авторское решение**. Тире в неполном предложении ставится при наличии паузы, при этом **логически выделена первая часть предложения**.